# Disk Capacity is Low, cannot produce more messages

Tags: node.js, activemq-artemis

Can anyone tell me how to implement ActiveMQ Artemis using the nodejs module stompit as I am getting error:

```
AMQ229119: Disk Capacity is Low, cannot produce more messages.
```

Comment: The drive of the machine running activeMQ seems to be near full...

Comment: It has free space around 15GB

Comment: I looked a bit into the [code](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/03971cf56012be6fe5ac4c06d601cdc4c693192d/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/paging/impl/PagingManagerImpl.java) and it seems like this happens if the `PageManager` thinks the disk is full (maybe there's a config-option for that?). There should also be more information in your logfiles

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who may have this same question in the future. If not, please clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ Artemis will automatically detect low disk capacity and block producers. This is calculated based on a percentage which is defined, by default, in `broker.xml`:

```xml
<max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
```

So if the disk is over 90% full the broker will block production of new messages.

Based on the size of your disk it could be that there actually is sufficient capacity to produce more messages. For example, if the total disk size was 1 terabyte and was 90% full then that would still leave 100 gigabytes of capacity. In cases like this the recommendation would be to increase the `<max-disk-usage>` value. Otherwise the recommendation would be to consume messages to free up the necessary disk space.